# Error while running Apache Hudi deltastreamer

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet, apache-hudi

I a trying to run Hudi deltastreamer on AWS EMR. Followed the steps in this blog. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewrecentblogposts.action?key=HUDI

But when I run the below spark submit, error comes:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '--table-type' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
            at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.initMainParameterValue(JCommander.java:936)
            at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:752)
            at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:340)
            at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:319)
```

Command I run is below:

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer \
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4 \
 --master yarn --deploy-mode client /usr/lib/hudi/hudi-utilities-bundle.jar \
--table-type COPY_ON_WRITE --source-ordering-field payment_date --source-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.sources.ParquetDFSSource \
--target-base-path s3://sakila-db/hudi-payment \
--target-table hudi-payment \
--transformer-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.transform.AWSDmsTransformer \
--payload-class org.apache.hudi.payload.AWSDmsAvroPayload \
--hoodie-conf hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field=order_id,hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field=staff_id,hoodie.deltastreamer.source.dfs.root=s3://sakila-db/sakila/payment
```

Please help.

Comment: AWSDmsAvroPayload was also not available until 0.5.1. Have you found a way around this?

Comment: I've been facing the same issue... Did you find a solution? (I'm trying to execute the spark-submit using ssh.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [EMR releases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html#emr-5290-release) the hudi version that is currently supported is 0.5.0-incubating. The steps you are following are for 0.5.1 where the `--table-type` parameter is the new name for the old `--storage-type` in 0.5.0.

Try rerunning using `--storage-type` instead of `--table-type` if you are using 0.5.0